# Create date dynamically in sql query

Tags: sql, datetime

Need a sql query where using an integer we can create date. By adding that number to current date.

Suppose my int varaible is `uptoDays`.

sql query should be like

```
.... where somedatetimecolumn <= (current_datetime + uptoDays)
```

I am using so SAP Crystal reports and due to some constrains only integer values are avail as dynamic parameters.

Answer (score 3):

[Looks like DateAdd](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/oss_notes_boj/sdn_oss_boj_bi/sap%28bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==%29/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes%7B6163636573733d36393736354636443646363436353344333933393338323636393736354637333631373036453646373436353733354636453735364436323635373233443330333033303331333233313331333333373331%7D.do) will do it:

```
DateAdd("D",uptoDays,getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which DBMS you are using. And I'm not sure if it is everywhere the same behaviour.

But the Micrsoft SQL Server handles `DateTimes` as numeric values. So you can cast between them. The reference date is the 01/01/1900. For example:

```
CAST(1 as datetime)  => 1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
CAST(100 as datetime) => 1900-04-11 00:00:00.000
```